# CSS background image and height

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
.main {
  min-height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('onepage_restaurant.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
}
```

but the div of class `.main` isn't showing up. Why?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: when i refresh in the browser it is just white background color

Comment: Did you get the file path right?

Comment: I would guess it's a bad file path as well, What happens if you add background-color: 'red'?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine unless you make sure that your parent element has a height greater than zero - otherwise your `.main` element will have no height either.

Also make sure that the file path to your image is correct. You can use the developer tools of your browser to check the height of your container and the image url.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.main {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(//placehold.it/500);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
```

Comment: but i want to be body 100%.

Comment: Then you have to set the height of the html to 100%, too

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help! I would appreciate an accept ;)

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the `min-height` of that element to `100%`. When you want to set the `height` of an element with percentage you need to set the `height` of the parent element to a specific value.

Answer (score 0):

Set the height in pixels. Example.

```
height: 100px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be either background image wrong path or, if you have no content, html, body height set to zero.
try this in your css

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
```